# Crawling a page using python

Tags: python, selenium, web-crawler

I am making a crawler which could be used for all the e-commerce websites. Currently, I am testing my crawler on the following websites.

[link 1](http://www.flipkart.com/mobiles/pr?p%5B%5D=sort%3Dfeatured&sid=tyy%2C4io&ref=3fdc36cd-f249-4398-814c-4bb53f2be61c)

[link 2](http://www.healthkart.com/sports/team-sports?navKey=CL-43&itracker=w%3aemenu|;p:2|;c%3ateam-sports|;)

[link 3](http://www.snapdeal.com/products/mobiles-mobile-phones?q=Price%3A738%2C62458&sort=plrty)

[link 4](http://www.amazon.in/gp/bestsellers/hpc/1374491031/ref=s9_ri_bw_clnk?pf_rd_m=A1VBAL9TL5WCBF&pf_rd_s=merchandised-search-9&pf_rd_r=07H71RVBE1TTANBX9Y0H&pf_rd_t=101&pf_rd_p=502687707&pf_rd_i=1374489031)

Individually, I am successful in crawling all the four websites, but when I was making a general crawler I couldnot figure out how to display more products. Eg.

In [link 1](http://www.flipkart.com/mobiles/pr?p%5B%5D=sort%3Dfeatured&sid=tyy%2C4io&ref=3fdc36cd-f249-4398-814c-4bb53f2be61c), I need to click show more results in order to get more products displayed.

In [link 2](http://www.healthkart.com/sports/team-sports?navKey=CL-43&itracker=w%3aemenu|;p:2|;c%3ateam-sports|;), I need to press load more to show more products.

In [link 3](http://www.snapdeal.com/products/mobiles-mobile-phones?q=Price%3A738%2C62458&sort=plrty), I just need to scroll down to get more products

In [link 4](http://www.amazon.in/gp/bestsellers/hpc/1374491031/ref=s9_ri_bw_clnk?pf_rd_m=A1VBAL9TL5WCBF&pf_rd_s=merchandised-search-9&pf_rd_r=07H71RVBE1TTANBX9Y0H&pf_rd_t=101&pf_rd_p=502687707&pf_rd_i=1374489031)
, next button is pressed to get more products.

Every website has a different class/tag for button, so how can I make it out whether to press button or scroll down.

Initially I have started with Selenium but it is not necessary, if any other module is better than selenium, I would love to use it.

Comment: `scrapy` is perfect for this

Comment: @Fabricator Will it allow me to search for a button if there is one without knowing the class/tag

Answer (score 0):

Scrapy actually won't work because your trying to interact with javascript.  You will want to stick with selenium.  firefox has an addon for selenium that allows you to record your actions on a browser then export it into python.  So clicking, loading, and scrolling are no problem.

To get the addon follow these instructions... http://www.wikihow.com/Download-Selenium-IDE-Addon

Comment: the xpath and classes and tags are totally different for different sites and i dont want to change the code every time I change website...I mean i should enter a link and it should automatically detect whether to press button or just scroll down, and if the button is to be pressed then, which one, so how to manage that, please give of this problem

Comment: Well if there is no common denominator to finding what user action it requires among all these sites, then it is impossible to make a general method that does everything you want.  You will have to break it up into different cases, which you could detect by looking at the domain of the site you want to scrape